# Read and write excel file with comments

Tags: r, excel

**Q.** Im looking for a way to preserve comments of an excel file after reading and manipulating.

**0. My excelfile: (cant share it with you!)**

[image]

**1. I want to read it like that:** (having the col comment in excel as col comment in R)

(with whatever library that does it. openxlsx would be best)

```
df<- data.frame(a=1:3,b=4:6,c=7:9)
comment(df$a) <- "Random comment" #is there a better practice to preserve the excel comment?
```

**2. Random manipulation of the data:**

```
df[2:3] <- df[2:3] * 2
df$d    <- "funny"
```

**3. Save the data** (it should look like this:)
[image]

**Edit:**

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- loadWorkbook("commented.xlsx")
df <- readWorkbook(wb)

df[2:3] <- df[2:3] * 2
df$d    <- "funny"
df <- rev(df)
df <- df[order(df$a,decreasing = T),]

writeData(wb, 1, df)
saveWorkbook(wb, "modified.xlsx")
```

A wonderful solution so far!

1. The comments stay stationary as seen by this little example.
2. I̶ ̶g̶e̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶a̶d̶d̶i̶t̶i̶o̶n̶a̶l̶ ̶e̶m̶p̶t̶y̶ ̶"̶c̶o̶m̶m̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶p̶o̶p̶ ̶u̶p̶ ̶w̶i̶n̶d̶o̶w̶"̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶u̶l̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶f̶i̶l̶e̶.̶ ̶I̶s̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶j̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶m̶e̶?̶  (workaround available!)

Comment: You might try the **tidyxl** [package](https://nacnudus.github.io/tidyxl/). I'm not sure if many others will pay any attention to formatting or comments.

Comment: `tidyxl` does not allow to write, as far as I know.

Comment: Were you hoping that the comments would follow the data transformations? Such that in the example, the comment would move with the `"a"` cell to D1?

Comment: Of course, that would be great if possible somehow. (I know I did not have that case covered in my OP ´:) )

Comment: Yeah I can see how that would be useful. However, I can't think of an easy way to tackle that. With `writeData()` you basically just rewrite the data rather than actually moving cells, so it won't "automatically" get handled. Maybe somebody else will come up with a solution for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with **openxlsx**: use `loadWorkbook()` to read in the original file, modify the data that you want, and finish up with `saveWorkbook()`. The comments will be preserved:

```r
library(openxlsx)

wb <- loadWorkbook("commented.xlsx")
df <- readWorkbook(wb)

df[2:3] <- df[2:3] * 2
df$d    <- "funny"

writeData(wb, 1, df)
saveWorkbook(wb, "modified.xlsx")

unlink(c("commented.xlsx", "modified.xlsx"))
```

**Sample data**:

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook("unknown")
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")

df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = 7:9)
writeData(wb, 1, df)

comment <- createComment("Random comment")
writeComment(wb, 1, 1, 1, comment)

saveWorkbook(wb, "commented.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks Mikko, great! Can you look at my comment in the `edit` section of my question?

Comment: @AndreElrico I had a look, and it seems that the empty comments show up with `loadWorkbook()` on any comments that were "visible" in the Excel file. Seems like a bug; a workaround for now would be to hide comments before reading.

Comment: I [opened an issue](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/401) about this.